# window location href for image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to add a share button to an image and currently the configuration in javascript is this:

```
url: window.location.href
```

I want the url to be the url to the image and not the entire page. Here is the config

```
    this.config = {
  enabled_networks: 0,
  protocol: ['http', 'https'].indexOf(window.location.href.split(':')[0]) === -1 ? 'https://' : '//',
  url: window.location.href,
  caption: null,
  title: (content = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:title"]') || document.querySelector('meta[name="twitter:title"]')) ? content.getAttribute('content') : (content = document.querySelector('title')) ? content.innerText : void 0,
  image: (content = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]') || document.querySelector('meta[name="twitter:image"]')) ? content.getAttribute('content') : void 0,
  description: (content = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:description"]') || document.querySelector('meta[name="twitter:description"]') || document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]')) ? content.getAttribute('content') : '',
```

Can someone tell me how to target the image as the url instead of the entire page?

Comment: what image? I don't see any mention of an image in that code.

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML - First off, images don't have their own `href`s and don't lead you anywhere if you click them, unless you wrap them in an anchor tag. Second, even if they did, their `onclick` attribute wouldn't give you the URL of that location.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel i thought something like this `$("#my_image").attr("onclick","window.location='" + HrefLink + "'");`

Comment: Why would you use jQuery to set the `onclick` attribute when you could simply do `$("#my_image").on("click", function() { window.location = ... });`? Either way, that is besides the point, as that is not what the OP was asking for.

Comment: document.images[0].src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
url: $("yourImageSelector").prop("src")
```

This will grab the image from the DOM, and will then grab the value of its `src` attribute, which is the URL of the image (note that this method will also convert the URL to the absolute URL for you).

Comment: will attr() convert relative urls? i know prop() does for src since that's what the browser provides, but does jq re-write attrib values ? that would seem to be a very bad thing if so...

Comment: Nope, you are correct, @dandavis. That was a mistake on my part. I will update. `.attr` reads attributes as plain-text

Answer (score 1):

your image html code:

```
  <img id="my_image" src="jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/images/logo-jquery.png" />
```

if try like this then your url variable will have your image url
or in your case it must be so

```
  this.config = {
     enabled_networks: 0,
     protocol: ['http', 'https'].indexOf(window.location.href.split(':')[0]) === -1 ? 'https://' : '//',
     url: $('#my_image').attr('src'),
     caption: null,
     title: (content = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:title"]') || document.querySelector('meta[name="twitter:title"]')) ? content.getAttribute('content') : (content = document.querySelector('title')) ? content.innerText : void 0,
     image: (content = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]') || document.querySelector('meta[name="twitter:image"]')) ? content.getAttribute('content') : void 0,
     description: (content = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:description"]') || document.querySelector('meta[name="twitter:description"]') || document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]')) ? content.getAttribute('content') : '',
```

Comment: How is this answer any different from mine, except that you made the mistake that I did that dandavis spotted and corrected me on?

Comment: I did not saw your answer, sorry mate